# Crear url manualmente en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, migration

La siguiente es una pregunta algo bastante complicada pero voy a ella.

Resulta que me toco migrar mi web con una **BD** con mucho contenido dentro de ella, pero el problema no es el contenido, si no que debo migrar  esta web a **wordpress** ya que son tablas distintas, porque la otra esta hecha en php puro con mysql pero, hay contenido dentro de esa BD que no voy a colocar, son cosas obsoletas lo que a mi me interesa es la tabla donde se encuentra el mayor numero de contenido que son post o publicaciones, migrarla va a ser un gran desafió para mi. Pero no sera gran problema el problema es que quiero que las url que se realizan por una function dentro de mi web sea la misma y se puedan generar en wordpress hay manera de hacer esto dentro de este **cms**? Existe algún problema con ello quisiera saber que código dentro de este **cms** puedo yo tocar para generar estas mismas **url's** por ejemplo:

```
misitio.com/trucos-juegos/pc/los-sims-4-14036.html
```

Aquí es donde la url asi => dominio-categoria del juego-una subcategoria del juego-nombre del juego-y la id del juego al final de la url con el **.html**

Mientras que otras son de esta forma:

```
misitio.com/cheats/
```

**y otras asi :**

```
misitio.com/trucos-playstation-4/
```

Estas ultimas no se mostraran el **.html** porque son categorías

Abra forma de poder colocar manualmente por el código php o por medio de **.htaccess** estas **urls**? que sean idénticas para no perder el trafico en google ya que la web tiene años online y no queremos que esto se haga

Comment: No se entiende bien tu pregunta. Primeramente, yo le quitaría definitivamente el `.html` al final, eso suena *a siglo pasado*, de hecho hay pocas URL hoy día que terminen por html. Luego, haría un patrón de migración, escrito, y sacaría las diferentes categorías que contienen las URLs viejas. Luego crearía esas mismas categorías en WP y asignaría a cada elemento su respectiva categoría. La idea es que, al crear cualquier post, cree una URL idéntica a la vieja, excepto por la terminación `.html`. Luego, para el tráfico que viene desde resultados viejos, crearía una regla `.htaccess`

Comment: Es decir que ¿lo quieres hacer es migrar las urls que tienes en una web a la nueva en WP?

Comment: @Orici Si eso es lo que quiero hacer ya que la web antigua esta obsoleta en cambio con WP puedo cambiar o instalar un theme, tambien puedo comprar plugins pagos y esas cosas